# How can I upload changes to my Gitlab repository?

Tags: gitlab

I uploaded my files to gitlab. Now I've updated them and I also want to send the changes to gitlab, but this does not work at all because git always says that there are no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish your local changes follow the 3 simple steps below:

1. `git add <filename>` or `git add *` to add everything
2. `git commit -m "Enter e message here"`
3. `git push`